is there is any way possible to download multiple files(.pkpass) on iphone?
I am trying to download multiple boarding passses in ios using blob.
initially I am using this
private downloadMultipleFiles(boardingPassURLs : string[]): void{
    boardingPassURLs.forEach((url) => {
      this.downloadFileService.downloadFileFromURL(url).subscribe((blob) => {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = objectUrl;
        a.download = 'filenameXYZ.pkpass';
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
      });
    });
    this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
  }

  downloadFileFromURL(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }

It works on windows for all browsers.
But when i chcecked iphone in safari it says

"Safari can not download this file."

I have tried these approaches which is mentioned below but it did'nt worked out either.

Tried with adding timeouts

  private downloadMultipleFiles(boardingPassURLs : string[]): void{
    boardingPassURLs.forEach((url) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.downloadFileService.downloadFileFromURL(url).subscribe((blob) => {
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = objectUrl;
          a.download = 'filenameXYZ.pkpass';
          a.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        });
      },500);
    });
    this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
  }


Added MIME content Type

private downloadMultipleFiles(boardingPassURLs: string[]): void {
    boardingPassURLs.forEach((url, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.downloadFileService.downloadFileFromURL(url).subscribe((blob) => {
          const modifiedBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
          const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(modifiedBlob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = objectUrl;
          a.download = 'filenameXYZ.pkpass';
          a.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        });
      }, index * 500);
    });
    this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
  }

  downloadFileFromURL(url: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
    });

    return this.http.get(url, { headers,responseType: 'blob' });
  }

In this scenario only the initial file was downlaoding, and that too was blank.

Tried MIME Type - 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass'
But it gaves the same error as > "Safari can not download this file."

Tried using Iframes


private downloadMultipleFiles(boardingPassURLs: string[]): void {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  
    boardingPassURLs.forEach((url, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.downloadFileService.downloadFileFromURL(url).subscribe((blob) => {
          const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
          const a = iframe.contentWindow?.document.createElement('a');
          if (a) {
            a.href = objectUrl;
            a.download = 'filenameXYZ.pkpass';
            a.click();
          }
  
          URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        });
      }, index * 500);
    });
    this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
  }

It did'nt worked either.

seems like a pretty generic message.  Did you check available drive space on the phone?  You should probably just return a file and let browser handle the stream.  Creating objectURLs will just create a copy.  (You can handle multiple, async file downloads via iframes)

Hey @browsermator,
Thanks for looking into the problem.
Yes, I have checked the space, and it was sufficient and also tried with the iframe approach which I mentioned above but it didn't worked either.

I think you'll need one user action per file.  Try to get it working with a single file first.  If that doesn't work it's probably just a quirk in Safari.... maybe make a query with Apple.

Hey @browsermator,
Not even a single file is getting downloaded in ios.
But I tried changing the MIME type to 'application/vnd-com.apple.pkpass'
Now the passes are downloading but only the last one gets downloaded.

that's a good sign, but it sounds like the requests are being aborted so that the last one is left.  Make sure each download is triggered via a user action and target a different iframe for each.  No need to create objectURLs.

Make sense,
Although I tried adding timeouts between each download and it's working now. 100ms time works for iOS.
But I wonder why adding timeout works?
As far as I have researched, without a timeout, if one file takes too long to download (due to network issues, slow server response, or file size), then in the meantime new download cascades over the previous one because files are downloading on a single thread because of JS nature which only makes the last file to get downloaded.
when we add a timeout in between downloading the files, then JS considers that as a separate task.

each request will abort the last.  You'd need to target another iframe, or even just set target to "_blank".  Let the browser handle the download.

I tried using the below MIME type and added delay between each download and it's working fine.

"application/vnd-com.apple.pkpass"

private downloadMultipleFiles(boardingPassURLs: string[]): void {
    const downloadObservables = boardingPassURLs.map((url) =>
      this.downloadFileService.downloadFileFromURL(url).pipe(
        map((blob) => {
          const modifiedBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/vnd-com.apple.pkpass' });
          const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(modifiedBlob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = objectUrl;
          a.download = `FilenameXYZ.pkpass`;
          a.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        }),
        delay(500),
      ),
    );
  
    of(...downloadObservables).pipe(
      concatMap((download$) => download$),
    ).subscribe({
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
            this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
      },
      complete: () => {
            this.loaderService.setIsLoaderVisible(false);
      },
    });
  }

